# How to make svn diff produce file that patch would apply, when svn cp or svn mv was used?

Tags: svn, merge, diff, patch

The scenario is:

1. svn cp or mv some file
2. modify that file
3. svn diff > mypatch

On other machine (same working copy, but no changes):

4. Try to apply mypatch.
5. Fail -> tries to modify unexistant file.

How can I make svn diff produce patch-appliable patch, or cleanly apply patch produced by svn diff in this case? I can't commit. I would like to preserve mergeinfo (because the obvious workaround is to add the file as totally new, without connection to the previous one).

Answer (score 64):

With subversion, you can specify which diff binary to use, and parameters to pass to it.  See [the manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re09.html) on svn diff.

You'd want to produce a regular patch file from a svn diff, so you'd want the svn diff to look like a normal diff.  Try this:

```
svn diff --diff-cmd /usr/bin/diff -x "-i -b" > mypatch
...
patch -p0 < mypatch
```

Proof of concept:

```
echo "newline" >> README.txt
svn diff --diff-cmd /usr/bin/diff -x "-i -b" > mypatch
cp README.txt README.txt.patched
svn revert README.txt
patch -p0 < mypatch
diff README.txt README.txt.patched
```

No difference in the two files after patching.

Comment: This doesn't work if there are property changes between branches though.

Comment: This isn't working for me. The patch file that is produced still shows the copied file as being a modification of an original file (e.g. it has lines beginning with - as well as lines that don't begin with - or +). Furthermore, an attempt at patching yields: "12 out of 14 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file". Have you tried this with a source file that actually has content, and a destination file that has content different from the source file?

Comment: i was looking for the exact same thing, and this worked a charm, thanks

Comment: Following OP's steps (svn mv, modify the new file) and your commands for diffing and patching, I get the same result as OP stated - patch complains that the new file doesn't exist, so it doesn't know what to patch.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to get rid of the svn properties as well in your patches, there is an option for that:

```
svn diff --patch-compatible > mypatch.diff
```

`svn help diff` says:

```
  --patch-compatible   : generate diff suitable for generic third-party
                         patch tools; currently the same as
                         --show-copies-as-adds --ignore-properties
```

Patches created this way are supposed to be compatible with the good old plain `patch` utility.

Comment: This came closer to the expected result than the answer with more votes. This one actually removes the content from the file that was moved, and adds the correct modifications for the new file. But it shows the original file as simply modified and having no content, and the new file as an unversioned file. Still, this is the best answer I see so far to the original question.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the `--show-copies-as-adds` option mentioned on the [**svn diff**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html) web page and described on the [**svn options**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.show_copies_as_adds) page?.

Answer (score -1):

Without understanding the specific scenario you're trying to work upon its hard to identify why you'd want to do this. I get the feeling you're trying to make controlled changes in an isolated environment so to avoid impacting other users/applications.

Could you solve this problem by;

- Create a branch for your code change
- Perform your copy/move and changes on the branch
- Get the other party to switch to this new code branch and carry on sharing this branch

When you've both agreed with the changes merge back into trunk using the --reintegrate argument and rm the branch?

This would
 * Maintain merge-info
 * Identify the copy/move and changes in version control 
 * Still isolate changes from other users
 * Would prevent incomplete changes during step 2 being an issue as you could just add more changes and update