# Including new files in SVN diff

Tags: svn, diff, patch

I have a script which builds my application, uploads it to a remote machine, runs a performance test there and captures some metrics that I care about. The script creates a patch file for the local modifications I make in my workspace and shows it along with the performance numbers. This helps me compare the effect of various tuning options. If I want to recreate my workspace at a later date, I can use the SVN revision number and the patch.

`svn diff` does not report a new files I add to the workspace unless I explicitly use `svn add` on them first. Is there some way to create a patch file which will include the new files also?

PS: A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159853/subversion-diff-including-new-files) but was not answered adequately, IMO.

Comment: How is that a problem? Preparing a patch with SVN is like preparing a commit. You run `svn status` and `svn diff` to see if all the pieces you need are there and *revert*, *add*, *rm* and edit the files until you're satisfied with your changes.

Comment: @Alexandre, I want a _scriptable_ way to capture my local changes in such a way that I can recreate the state of the workspace later with the info "this delta, applied to revision number XYZ" or something similar.

Comment: You might be able to use `svn diff --show-copies-as-adds` to do what you want, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2185988/131504

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To make `svn diff`  include all the unversioned files from your local working copy you have to add these files first. `svn diff` outputs the same changeset that `svn commit` would use.

If you know for sure that all unversioned files should be added here's what you could do.

Prepare a list of unversioned files by taking from the output of `svn status` all the lines that start with a question mark:

```
svn status | grep ^? | sed -r 's/^\? +//' > ../unversioned_files_list.txt
```

You can then pass that list of files to `svn add`using `xargs`:

```
xargs -r -d '\n' svn add < ../unversioned_files_list.txt
```

And then produce the patch:

```
svn diff > ../my_patch.patch
```

If you don't want to keep those files added, use the list of files to unadd them:

```
xargs -r -d '\n' svn rm --keep-local < ../unversioned_files_list.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Alexandre, that looks like it might just work. I will try it and get back.

Comment: I cannot find better words to congratulate you as Denis did. :-)

Comment: This is a really great answer!

Comment: Note that for mac it's 'sed -E'.

Answer (score 14):

Thanks Alexandre. At first, his approach didn't work in my case. I was sure all new files were maked `A` in `svn status`, however, the diff file was still empty. Finally, I found the difference in `svn status` outputs, the fourth columns in my case are all populated with `+`, like:

```
$ svn st
M      .
A  +    New.java
```

This means the item is scheduled for `addition-with-history`[1]. This typically happens when you `svn move` or `svn copy` a file or directory[2]. In my case, the `New.java` is `svn merged` from another branch, including previous commit history in that branch. Let's removed these history information.

First, find all `addition-with-history` items:

```
svn status | grep ^A | sed -r 's/^A[ +]+//' > /tmp/add_list
```

Optionally, remove directory paths in `/tmp/add_list` to avoid warnings in next step.

Next, remove their history commit information by `svn remove`:

```
xargs -r -d '\n' svn remove --keep-local --force < /tmp/add_list
```

Then, go back to Alexandre's solution to add them to subversion again and get the diff.

References:

```
[1]http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html
[2]http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_tool_guides/version_control_with_subversion/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html
```