# How to create patch file for deleted/renamed/moved files?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, patch

I'm using TortoiseSVN. As shown [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-patch.html), I can use `Create patch` and `Apply patch` for modified files, and it works OK.

However, when I delete, rename or moved a certain files, then choose `Create patch`. The patch file is empty.

Someone ask [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317649/how-to-make-svn-diff-produce-file-that-patch-would-apply-when-svn-cp-or-svn-mv), but the answers are not satisfactory. Also, I don't want the command-line solutions.

Supposed I'm creating a ticket telling the source owner to delete, rename or move some files.
How to overcome this issue ?

Answer (score -1):

It should usually work. But make sure you select files/folders you have deleted while creating patch. 
Right click on the project->select "create patch"-> now make sure that **you select the files/folders you have deleted before you click OK**

Comment: i was able to select the deleted files and give a name to the PATCH file but stays empty upon saving